# Jquery MaskMoney asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Eu utilizo o `Jquery` `MaskMoney` nos meus `inputs` para tratar os `decimais`, até ai tudo bem, mas reparei que quando digito valores acima de ***1.000,00*** onde o `MaskMoney` me joga o ponto(.) no valor, Quando eu salvo o `Bind` do `Mvc` me traz esse valor ***Zerado***. Porém quando o valor é até **mil** onde não vai o **ponto** (999,99) o valor chega correto na `Controller` segue minha `Controller` e minha `Model`:

**`Controller`**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(Produto produto, string returnUrl)
{
    TempData["mensagem"] = "PRODUTO EDITADO COM SUCESSO!";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(produto.Cest))
    {
        produto.Cest = produto.Cest.Replace(".", "");
    }
    produto.Codigo = produto.Codigo.Split(Convert.ToChar("."))[1];
    ctx.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return Redirect("~" + returnUrl);
    //  return RedirectToAction("sucesso", "produto");
}
```

**`Model`**

```
public decimal Custo { get; set; }
```

**`View`**

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <label for="Custo">Custo</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Custo, new { @class = "form-control decimal required" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai ter que criar o seu próprio [Model Binder](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2012/05/06/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-parte-1-defaultmodelbinder/) para tratar deste caso específico de conversão de número decimal com localização (a formatação brasileira).

segue uma classe de exemplo para esse model binder de decimal:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Esta classe esta extraindo um valor decimal dos parametros do form postado e transformando em valor `decimal`

Aí, para que o MVC utilize a sua classe de binder, basta acrescentar essa linha no método `Application_Start` dor arquivo `Global.asax.cs`

assim:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

    // All that other stuff you usually put in here...
}
```

Caso queira ler um pouco mais sobre essa solução, ter mais alguma explicação, encontrei ela no blog do Phil Haack: [Model Binding Decimal Values](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/)

Comment: Sensacional , funcionou perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado